# Reading HTTP Messages in Java

Tags: java, http, parsing

First of all, I'll admit this is a school project, so I need more of just direction, rather than actual code.  Also, I cannot use the java.net.HTTPURLConnection and java.net.URL classes to help out...

Ok... I'm creating a HTTP server in Java, but having trouble reading HTTP messages.  I need to allow persistent connections (when using HTTP/1.1 and no Connection: close), which is already working.  But because of the persistence, there might be multiple requests coming down the pipeline.

I know I can use the Content-Length header to determine how long the message body will be, in bytes.  After that, the next message will come down the pipe.

My questions...

- Should I read in the message byte by byte or char by char, or can I read in line by line?  Going line by line would be fine until hitting the message body...
- Should the message body be saved in byte format, or is String ok (I know HTML is fine, but will images, etc. break if going through a String?)
- Is there a scanner that will let me read line by line, and then when I hit the message body, call a getBytes( contentLength ), and it gives me the body?

Thanks again!

Edit: I do not have to support chunked or compressed data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest reading into byte-arrays. And don't read line wise, but read in chunks of bytes (you can try to use content-length as your chunk size. Beware that read(byte[]) returns the number of bytes actually read and you still may have to call it several times).

Also beware of chunked encoding, although I admit that I do not know whether servers must support this since I always just cared for coding clients.

Comment: Thanks for the post.  I'll see what others have to say as well.  I just modified the question to note that I don't have to worry about chunked encoding (forgot to mention that).

Comment: Ok... so how do I know what the content-length is if I haven't gotten been able to parse any headers yet?

Comment: @mikesir87: Well, good point ;-). At this point you really do have to read line wise. The easiest way will be to read character wise until you recognize the sequence '\r','\n','\r',\'n', which will terminate the header section. Up to this point you add every character into a StringBuffer. Then you have the header, can analyze and continue reading byte array's. This method is not very good for performance, but easy to implement.

Comment: Ok.  To follow up, I did go ahead and do it reading byte by byte.  I would try to keep it relatively line by line (with my byte buffer), and that would allow me to quickly see if it was an empty line.  As I went through, I looked out for the Content-Length header.  Then, I snagged the body, with length of the Content-Length.  Everything is working out!  Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I second yankee's opinion - at the lower level you should read into a byte array. This will allow you to work both with html and images. At a higher level, you can always convert the html pieces into strings with a specific encoding. You are better off choosing your encoding at the higher level, not the lower one.

Use a buffer and fill it every time with new bytes. As yankee said, you'll need to repeat the calls to `read` method and check the return value.

Comment: Any particular class that you recommend to use for reading in?